# Common table expression defined but not used

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I can't figure out why I am getting this error. I definitely am trying to use the cte named "dvr_base". You can see in the inner select there is a join on dvr_base with aliad d.  All of the "d." columns in the select say "the multi-part column could not be bound"

```
    with dvr_base (program, cawpid, cecode, costrep, period, hours, direct, overhead, mhxdev, plwdev, ganda, comlabor, comganda, tcost)
as
    (
        select
            program,
            cawpid,
            cecode,
            costset,
            right('0000' + cast(datepart(year, pd_finish) as varchar(4)), 4) + right('00' + cast(datepart(month, pd_finish) as varchar(2)), 2),
            sum(hours),
            sum(direct),
            sum(overhead),
            sum(mhxdev),
            sum(plwdev),
            sum(ganda),
            sum(COMLABOR),
            sum(COMGANDA),
            sum(direct+overhead+mhxdev+plwdev+ganda+comlabor+comganda)
        from
            tphase join costdetl u on tphase.class = u.class and u.instance = @costdetlid
            join rcutoff r on tphase.df_date between r.pd_start and r.pd_finish
        where
            tphase.program = @project and
            tphase.df_date <= @statusdate and
            r.instance = @cutoffid
        group by
            tphase.program,
            tphase.cawpid,
            tphase.cecode,
            u.costset,
            r.pd_finish
    )

select
    c.program as ProjectID,
    c.ca3 as "Control Acct",
    c.descrip as "Control Acct Description",
    c.ca2 as OBS,
    c.ca1 as WBS,
    d.cecode as Resource,
    w.d1 as "Resource Type",
    d.costrep as "Cost Type",
    d.period as "YYYYMM",
    d.hours as Hours,
    d.direct as Direct,
    d.overhead as Overhead,
    d.mhxdev as MHX,
    d..plwdev as PLW,
    d..ganda as "G&A",
    d.COMLABOR as "COM Labor",
    d..COMGANDA) as "COM G&A",
    d.tcost as "Total Cost"
from
    cawp c join dvr_base d on
    c.program = d.program and c.cawpid = d.cawpid
    join calcdesc w on d.cecode = w.cecode and w.calcfile = @calcfile
where
    c.program = @project and
order by
    c.program,
    c.ca3,
    c.descrip,
    c.ca2,
    c.ca1,
    d.cecode,
    w.d1,
    d.period
;
```

Comment: @dfundako the columns are named in the cte. Look at the first line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few of issues in your query:

1. Line `d..COMGANDA) as "COM G&A",` has an extra closing parenthesis and an extra dot;
2. Line `c.program = @project and` has an extra `and`;
3. Multiple lines have an extra dot (ex: `d..COMGANDA`). It should be a single dot `d.COMGANDA`.

Once you fix the above issues the ***Common table expression defined but not used*** error goes away.

Comment: The first line also has a second period at the beginning of the line.

Comment: @user2378895 pleasure to be able to help. Please mark this as the answer when you get a chance.

Comment: I apologise on behalf of @Rahul